# .wait_variable(var) causing gui to freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my Tkinter app, I am trying to wait for a button press to allow the code to move on with .wait_variable(var). This code works with the same button at the beginning of the program but it does not work at a specific part. Here is a sample of my code(part of gui is skipped because it is far too long.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

continue_button = tk.Button(score_frame, text = 'CONTINUE BUTTON', fg = 'green',justify = CENTER , relief = GROOVE, font = ('Courier', 18), command = lambda : var.set(1))
continue_button.place(relx = 0.70, rely = 0.55, relheight = 0.45, relwidth = 0.30)
```

Here is an example of where this works

```
var = tk.IntVar()
while True:
    continue_button.wait_variable(var)
    if len(buttonsCompared) == 2:#this line checks the length of a list holding two unrelated buttons
         break
    else:
         #do something else unrelated
```

Here is the piece of code that does not work. The error occurs on both branches of the if statements, which leads me to believe that it is a problem with the .wait_variable() because both sides have very different code. Additionally, I did a test where I printed to the console before and after both waits, and it seems that both statements get printed out before and after but then the application freezes. There is no error message, all I see is a spinning pinwheel when I move my cursor over the application.

```
       if firstButtonValue == secondButtonValue:
            #some unrelated code
            continue_button.wait_variable(var)
            #some unrelated code

       else:
           #some unrelated code
           continue_button.wait_variable(var)
           #some unrelated code
```

Some additional info: all of the none gui code(the last two bits)are in a while true below the gui code but before the mainloop not contained in any function. Additionally, there is no code affecting the continue_button command or and no use of continue_button.wait_variable(var).

I have searched all over the internet and stack overflow, but I have found no other issues similar to this one with a solution that works or makes sense given my current code.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how I can fix it?(I am a beginner btw)

Comment: _"Here is the piece of code that does not work. The error occurs on both branches of the if statements"_ - what is the error? You don't show any errors in your question. Also, it would help if you could post a complete [mcve].

Comment: Are you ever setting `var` back to its original value?  Calling `.set(1)` on it will only trigger `wait_variable()` if it actually changes the value.

Comment: @jasonharper No, I did not do that however I have added that and it changed nothing. After testing some more, here is what I have realized. When I remove the .wait_variables(var) parts from the bottom section, the top section one does not work if the if statement is true. Additionally, I can now add as many .wait_variable(var) to the bottom section as I want and it will not freeze until the last one.